# Google Analytics - find exit rate for events, rather than pages?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a single-page application, and I am tracking events on the page, in Google Analytics, passing our internal user ID and timestamp as attributes on the event.

I would like to know the best way to find the top "bounce" (UPDATE: "exit" is a better term for this) events - i.e. events that are more than averagely likely to be the last event that a user fires.

<s>I *think* I can do this by extracting the raw event data from the GA API, and simply running my own analyses on it, using the timestamps. Is this correct?</s> (UPDATE: It seems not, because GA doesn't allow the export of raw event data.)

Is there any way to do this within the GA interface? I think I'm right in saying that the Event Flow won't show me the **overall** exit rates for a particular event.

I'm looking to create information like this:

- create new document: last event 10% of the time it was fired
- edit document: last event 5% of the time it was fired
- turn on track changes: last event 80% of the time it was fired

So that I can spot which events look problematic, like the last one in this example.

Comment: "bounces" are single page view sessions.   It doesn't make sense to think of events that way because events always happen on a page.   So there will always be two things: an even and a page.   Maybe you are looking at "exits"?   Exit pages are the last page in the session.  In that case the "Events Flow" report should be able to help you: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2521316?hl=en

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean exits not bounces. Sadly the Event Flow doesn't really work, because it shows each event at multiple points in the flow: I want to know the overall stats for each event, and to do that I'd have to manually add up all the numbers each time the event is shown.

Comment: You can export raw event data if you set the Hit Timestamp (hit level) and GA Client ID (user level) as custom dimensions: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/#4. Not sure of your specifics, but you could send all events also as a virtual pageview into a new View and filter these virtual pageviews from the other Views. It'll effectively double you event hit count, if you're sending lots of event hits, maybe you're only interested in specific events, so only send those as virtual pageviews.

Answer (score 1):

for me it sounds like you are the first who really need to use Event Flow chart.

Behavior / Events / Events Flow

Have you tried. But event's have to be equal for bettter results, like not a page view or scrolling which you accure every single time. You could make a segment with all your matter segments and see Event Flow for that segment.